# vhost redirect non exist subdomains

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I have this in my vhost file which direct all sub domains which do not exist to the main www.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I have at the moment is that some people are linking to my website with `www.mysite.com.` notice the `.` at the end. This is causing the CMS to break.

Is there a way to modify this ServerAlias or an alternative way so that this has a wild card at the end? I tried adding a `*` but this didn't work.

This is the full vhost for this domain:

```
# DEV
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/subdomain/dev/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public/webapp>
        RewriteEngine Off
        <Files *>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </Files>
        <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g|css|js|swf|flv|htc|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$">
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public/webapp/shared>
        <Files *>
            order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect for non existent subdomains
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have disabled .htaccess thats the reason for all the `<Directory>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this vhost is the first one, you do not *need* ServerAliases.

The first-listed vhost will by definition receive all requests that do not match a specific virtualhost's ServerName.

Remove the ServerAlias and make sure this vhost is loaded first.

Comment: Sadly no this is the last vhost for this domain. I quickly tested as you suggested by removing the other vhost and get the same problem.

Comment: ...so order it to make it the first.